# Как выполнить скрипт на bash в системном вызове system()?

Tags: c, bash

У меня есть скрипт на bash, который необходимо вставить в программу на языке СИ. Знаю, что отдельные команды bash можно вставлять в сишный код с помощью системного вызова. Например так: system("rm text.txt");.
Возможно ли с помощью system() выполнить не одну команду, а целый скрипт? Кроме того скрипт содержит в себе переменную, определённую в самом начале программы на СИ

Comment: Конечно, можно. Передайте в system() путь к вашему скрипту

Comment: Вот только "скрипт содержит в себе переменную, определённую в самом начале программы на СИ" - это как ?!!!

Comment: @Sergey, через `setenv()` по всей видимости...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Наверное, Вы правы.

Comment: Не стоит вызывать скрипт на shell из программы на Си, проблем с безопасностью выше крыши.